# Animating Toolbar with LayoutTransition

Tags: android, android-animation, android-toolbar

## What I'd like to achieve

My app has a `Toolbar` which contains 2 `AutoCompleteTextView`.
I'd like to show the second one only when the user selected someting in the first one, and hide it again if the first one is cleared (I have a 'X' in the `AutoCompleteTextView` to clear it).

I'd like the `Toolbar` to animate between this two states, expanding it and fading in the second `AutoCompleteTextView` when something is selected in the first one, and fading out the second `AutoCompleteTextView` and collapsing the `Toolbar` when the first one is cleared.

## What I tried, but didn't work

I tried using `LayoutTransition`, both in XML setting `android:animateLayoutChanges` to true, and in code declaring a `LayoutTransition` and setting it to the `LinearLayout` containing both my `AutoCompleteTextView`s.

**The first time I tried it this way:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle.Vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- TOOLBAR -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/ToolbarStyle">

        <!-- i set the LayoutTransition on THIS ONE -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linear_toolbar">

            <!-- AUTOCOMPLETE market -->
            <com.mwd.shoppinglist.Utility.AutoCompleteTextViewNoFilter
                android:id="@+id/shop_chooser"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Autocomplete"
                android:hint="@string/chooseShop"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"/>

            <!-- AUTOCOMPLETE product -->
            <com.mwd.shoppinglist.Utility.AutoCompleteTextViewNoFilter
                android:id="@+id/item_chooser"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Autocomplete"
                android:hint="@string/autoCompleteHint"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_cancel_dark"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <!-- RECYCLER VIEW -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <!-- TEMP TEXTVIEW -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_temp1"
        android:text="@string/pick_a_market"
        style="@style/TempTextView"/>

    <!-- BUTTON -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_btn_start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_start"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `Toolbar` contains a `LinearLayout` to which I set a `LayoutTransition` in code. This one handled the appearing pretty well: the `Toolbar` expands and the second `AutoCompleteTextView` fades in.

**The problem was on the disappearing**: the `Toolbar` collapses instantly, while I could still see the second `AutoCompleteTextView` on the white background of my `RecyclerView`, then after some time the `AutoCompleteTextView` fades out and the `Toolbar` expands and collapses once really fast.

**The second time I tried this:**

```
<!-- i set the LayoutTransition on THIS ONE -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle.Vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/linear_toolbar">

    <!-- TOOLBAR -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/ToolbarStyle">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- AUTOCOMPLETE market -->
            <com.mwd.shoppinglist.Utility.AutoCompleteTextViewNoFilter
                android:id="@+id/shop_chooser"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Autocomplete"
                android:hint="@string/chooseShop"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"/>

            <!-- AUTOCOMPLETE product -->
            <com.mwd.shoppinglist.Utility.AutoCompleteTextViewNoFilter
                android:id="@+id/item_chooser"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Autocomplete"
                android:hint="@string/autoCompleteHint"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_cancel_dark"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <!-- RECYCLER VIEW -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <!-- TEMP TEXTVIEW -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_temp1"
        android:text="@string/pick_a_market"
        style="@style/TempTextView"/>

    <!-- BUTTON -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_btn_start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_start"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This time the disappearing was handled well: the `AutoCompleteTextView` fades out and then the `Toolbar` collapses.

This time, **the problem was on the appearing:** the `AutoCompleteTextView` fades in on the white background of my `RecyclerView` and after some time the `Toolbar` expands.

**Both times** the appearing/disappearing of the second `AutoCompleteTextView` was handled by code setting `Visibility` to `VISIBLE` or `GONE`.

**I also tried** using two `Toolbar`s with an `AutoCompleteTextView` each, sliding in/out the second one, but I really think this looks *ugly-ish* in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get LayoutTransition to do what you want it to do, you can use [Android-Transition](https://github.com/kaichunlin/android-transition) library, and add the following code:

```
    final Animation animAutoComplete = ViewTransitionBuilder.transit(chooser).alpha(1f, 0f).range(0f, 0.7f).buildAnimation();
    //delayHeight(0) is required since the calculation requires current height, but it's still 0 when onCreate(Bundle) is called
    final Animation animAutoComplete2 = ViewTransitionBuilder.transit(chooser).delayHeight(0).range(0.7f, 1f).buildAnimation();
    final AnimationManager am = new AnimationManager();
    am.addAnimation(animAutoComplete2);
    am.addAnimation(animAutoComplete);

    //change this to suit your need
    findViewById(R.id.main_btn_start).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            am.cancelAnimation();
            am.setReverseAnimation(reverse);
            am.startAnimation(400);

            reverse = !reverse;
        }
    });
```

Note that you have to either download the whole project or fork it, as some of the code above aren't in the Gradle-importable releases.

Comment: I don't understand, isn't this just an alpha animation?